# Export all address from bitcoind on one server to bitcoind on another server

Tags: bitcoind, wallet, wallet.dat

I need to install `bitcoind` on a new server, but I already have many addresses in use on the old server. If I want to reuse all of those addresses on the new server, do I need to copy just the `wallet.dat` file or all files in the Bitcoin data directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To re-use the same addresses with the new server, it will be sufficient to copy just the `wallet.dat`. That single file contains the private keys to all receiving addresses that have been used since the `wallet.dat` file was originally created.

I would recommend copying across the `wallet.dat`, then making sure your addresses are there and available in `bitcoind` on the new server. If they are, then the wallet was copied over successfully and you're good to go.

As @Jannes mentioned, you will need to turn off `bitcoind` on both servers before you do the copy.

Comment: Turn OFF bitcoind on both servers before doing the copying. Don't delete the file from the old server until you're sure it works on the new server.